# Unity broadcast live video

Tags: unity-game-engine, broadcast, live-video

I'm developing an app in unity, that receives the live video from another device through a local wifi network, and the app must broadcast it through internet to watch live by another user. Can anybody suggest a way?

Comment: Windows Media Server

Comment: Your question kinda reads as _["where they want to start, and where they want to end, but there are way too many pieces to fill in"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/223458/284550)_ and if so might be considered too broad.  Consider adding more information about how you would like your problem solved, perhaps with a code sample of what you have already tried.  Good luck!

Comment: I do nothing yet, but I want to broadcast a video from a unity app and watch it through another user who use the unity app in another device through internet

Comment: Yup, got it the first time thanks. ;)

Comment: I just wanted to introduce way